# Animation freezes when BackgroundWorker is running - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a BackgroundWorker that runs while a loading animation occurs. However, the animation freezes when the BackgroundWorker is running. Is there any way to rectify this?

My code is below...

```
ReadOnly LoaderStoryboard As Animation.Storyboard
ReadOnly LoaderStartStoryboard As Animation.Storyboard
ReadOnly LoaderEndStoryboard As Animation.Storyboard
Private Delegate Sub mydelegate()

Public Sub New()
   LoaderStartStoryboard = TryFindResource("LoaderStartStoryboard")
   LoaderEndStoryboard = TryFindResource("LoaderEndStoryboard")
End Sub

Private Sub FontWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
   Dim deli As mydelegate = New mydelegate(AddressOf AddFonts)
   FontGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, deli)
End Sub

Private Sub FontWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
   LoaderEndStoryboard.Begin()
End Sub

Private Sub GetFonts()
   ' Process starts here '
   LoaderStartStoryboard.Begin()
   FontWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub AddFonts()
   ' This sub performs under the BackgroundWorker '
End Sub
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you aren't really doing work on a background thread.  You're doing everything on the UI thread.  (That's what happens when you call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from the background thread; the result is that the only thing the background thread is doing is the trivial work of setting up the delegate, and then the actual work goes back to the UI thread to perform.)

Comment: Could you suggest a solution to avoid this problem? Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to address it is to stop doing the entire workload on the UI thread, assuming that's possible (you don't include the contents of `AddFonts` so I'm not sure what it does).  Presumably you're using the dispatcher because part of the workflow involves a UI update, but if that's only a small part of the workflow, then just dispatch that specific piece and keep the rest on the background worker.  If that's not possible, there are other alternatives, but I'd prefer to use them as a last resort.

Comment: ```AddFonts``` does involve a UI update. It creates a series of buttons for each font and adds them to a grid. What would you say is the best solution given this?

Comment: Use a task to get the data or whatever you do to get the list of fonts. Run that on a background thread using await Task.Run. That task returns a list of viewmodels. Each viewmodel has the data for a font. Use an itemscontrol of some sort to display the buttons. Bind the itemssource of that to an observablecollection and give that your list of font viewmodels. Use itemtemplate to template each into a button.

Comment: Thanks @Andy could you give some code for this so I can also mark it as answered?